# Why doesn't Python use ^ to denote squaring a number but uses ** instead?

Tags: python

A few languages I've seen utilise the `^` symbol, and it doesn't seem to be reserved for anything in Python. It sort of confuses me as well since the `^` symbol is (very) well known and Python is supposed to be easy to use, which is not as much the case in using the `**`.

Is there any logical explanation for this? I mean it's not a huge difference, but just curious for this choice?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting rationale for choosing operator symbols.

Comment: What's with the upvote spree? Gimme.

Comment: @user2864740 I tried to be as objective as possible in my question and to not ask for opinions or "what's better"...

Comment: @Manfred The overall problem of similar "historic" rationale question is that *unless* one can actually find some historical documentation (e.g. Guido discussing the choice), answers often cannot be substantiated very well. It is what it is. (Although, if `^` was pow, how could one bit-wise xor *and* pow integers? But again.. it's history now.)

Comment: I learned FORTRAN first, and for me `**` was well known and easy to use.  It's all subjective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Guido says](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/early-language-design-and-development.html) "Python’s first and foremost influence was ABC, a language designed in the early 1980s by Lambert Meertens, Leo Geurts and others at CWI.". [`x` raised to the power `y` was implemented as `x**y` in ABC](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/abc/qr.html). ABC itself was influenced by SETL & ALGOL 68.

Answer (score 9):

Because `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. This is the same for many languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), [Ruby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm), and certainly others.

Comment: Was going to -1 until you added the note about the history in C. You wouldn't happen to know why they did that in C, would you?

Comment: @2rs2ts That's funny, because it was a correct answer, even before that addition.

Comment: Sure, but what would explain that choice? Why not use `^` for exponentiation and something else for XOR? It doesn't really answer the "why" until you say that it's been convention, at which point it makes sense why Python does this.

Comment: Why not use the `unicorn` operator? Please reserve downvotes for incorrect answers.

Comment: +1 And you might even add Perl for using ** for the power function ;)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Thanks - it seems [duffymo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23230771/119527) is pointing out languages that use `**` for exponentiation, where mine was giving rationale for why `^` was used for XOR.

Comment: After your edit, that is.

Answer (score 3):

FORTRAN is another language that uses the ** notation for power.  It predates both Python and C by a lot, so perhaps it was an influence on the BDFL.